# Adding plain text to xml using XmlSerializer

Tags: java, android, xml, android-tv

I'm trying to achieve this using XmlSerializer:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tv SYSTEM "xmltv.dtd">

<tv>
    <channel id="com.example.android.sampletvinput.2-1" repeat-programs="true">
        <display-name>Google</display-name>
        <display-number>2-1</display-number>
        <icon src="http://storage.googleapis.com/android-tv/images/google.png" />
    </channel>
```

I am already getting mostly all of it, except for

```
<!DOCTYPE tv SYSTEM "xmltv.dtd">
```

If I try to add it using serializer.text, it just returns `&lt;!DOCTYPE tv SYSTEM "xmltv.dtd"&gt;`

**How should I approach this to have an exact replica?**

Code:

```
private static String xmlCreate() {
        XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        try {
            serializer.setOutput(writer);
            serializer.startDocument("UTF-8", false);
            serializer.startTag("","<!DOCTYPE tv SYSTEM \"xmltv.dtd\">");
            serializer.startTag("", "tv");
            //serializer.setPrefix("id", "0000");
            serializer.startTag("", "channel");
            serializer.attribute("", "id", "0000");
            serializer.attribute("", "repeat-programs", "true");

            serializer.startTag("", "display-name");
            serializer.text("GOOGLE");
            serializer.endTag("", "display-name");

            serializer.startTag("", "display-number");
            serializer.text("1111");
            serializer.endTag("", "display-number");

            serializer.endTag("", "channel");
            serializer.endTag("", "tv");
            serializer.endDocument();
            Log.d(TAG,"DOCUMENT: " + writer.toString());
            return writer.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer.
By using serializer.docdecl("tv SYSTEM "xmltv.dtd") it creates

`<!DOCTYPE tv SYSTEM "xmltv.dtd">`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using Character Data marked section which means that the data in the tag should be interpreted as plain-text, not XML. It would go something like that

```
<![CDATA[
.. your xml ..
]]>
```